# How to include a custom external css link (like bootstrap css) to a single REACT component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to add a custom css imported from bootstrap website, as it is not a css file which i can import inside my react component
How to import this type of css for a React component?

```
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: If you are using npm or yarn to manage your dependencies you can add Bootstrap to your package.json and import the relevant sass files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `npm` to manage your dependencies for React, you can add Bootstrap as a dependency and import the relevant files.

**Example:**

In the command line (inside the directory where your `package.json` file is):

```sh
npm install --save bootstrap
```

In the component code, where your other imports are (usually at the beginnig of the script section):

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

this can have a caveat: the imported style may be conflicting with your other styles so you may have to make sure this doesn't have any adverse effects.

Comment: thanks, yes you are right...the imported style is distrubing the old layout a lot

Comment: You can also import the parts you need in your main scss file. The Bootstrap package in NPM has scss partials. You can include them one by one, based on what do you need. However, it still may cause layout issues (albeit less likely).